# How to access a child component from a parent component using the "ref" attribute-EXTJS

Tags: javascript, extjs

How to access a child component from a parent component:

code:

```
(function() {
    var NS = Q.Util.namespace('path');
    var $cls = NS.SomeComp = function(cfg) {
        $cls.superclass.constructor.call(this, Ext.apply({
            steps: [{
                name: $L('ABC')
            }, {
                name: $L('ABC Def'),
                ref: "abcDef",
                view: {
                    cls: path.Mycomponent
                },
                edit: {
                    cls: path.Mycomponent
                },
                create: {
                    cls: path.Mycomponent
                }
            }])
        }, cfg));
    };
    Ext.extend($cls, ExtendingComponnet, {
        init: function() {
            this.steps.filter(function(i){if(i.ref==="abcDef"){return i;}})[0] // give me the object and not the component
            return false;
        },

    });
})();
```

I'm trying to access the `Mycomponent` which is a part of steps inside the panel. So `this.steps` gives me an object:

```
{
                name: $L('ABC Def'),
                ref: "abcDef",
                view: {
                    cls: path.Mycomponent
                },
                edit: {
                    cls: path.Mycomponent
                },
                create: {
                    cls: path.Mycomponent
                }
            }
```

But what I want is the entire `Mycomponent` that I would use to access functions, configs defined in it. How can I do it?any ideas?

Comment: Don't use the `ref` attribute. It's largely deprecated. Look at the `reference` configuration and view controllers.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli ref is correct. If I am not mistaken, this is extjs 3.

Comment: I believe steps is just a plain configuration which must be used by parent superclass constructor. From what I can recall, parent constructor/component which simplifies the creation of window with view,edit & create window in same panel, contains logic for processing the steps configuration and in turn creates items configuration for panel.